# coldfusion making better use of cfparam

Tags: coldfusion, query-string

In our index files, at the top of the file we will generally `<cfparam>` out the variables that will come from the URL, form or wherever. However, we are getting a lot of bots hitting us with things like **www.example.com/survey/index.cfm?nPageNumber=-1** meaning a cfparam like this:

```
<cfparam name="request.parameters.nPageNumber" default="1" type="numeric" />
```

will fail due to the nonsense a bot is putting into the querystring.

I find myself increasingly having to write my cfparams like this:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(request.parameters,"nPageNumber") AND isNumeric(request.parameters.nPageNumber)>
    <cfparam name="request.parameters.nPageNumber" default="1" type="numeric" />
<cfelse>
    <cfset request.parameters.nPageNumber = 1>
</cfif>
```

While this solves the issue, I can't help but feel this solution is not the best/most efficient.  Am I using `cfparam` correctly or are there better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensuring the existence of a variable, and validating its value are two separate tasks.

In the case of `URL` and `Form` your existence code should be something like:

```
<cfparam name="URL.nPageNumber" default="1" type="string">
```

The use of `type` there is just to ensure that nothing truly bizarre has happened such as the value is a struct or query, etc.  You don't want to get specific at this point since you want a graceful error and not at 500 for the user.

Once you've made sure that the value exists, you then need to validate the value.

```
<cfif isNumeric(URL.nPageNumber) EQ false OR URL.nPageNumber LT 1 OR URL.nPageNumber GT Variables.MaxPages>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(Variables.ErrorArray, "Incorrect page number requested.")>
</cfif>
```

You could force the value to something sane, but see [Martian Headsets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/03/17.html) for a counter argument to the [robustness principle](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-13).

Providing an error message instead of "displaying something sane" will inform your users that they are doing something wrong, and means you're not forced to use [canonical urls](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) if you're not already (although you should be).

Yes, it's more work.  You can devise some abstraction for it all, but at the raw level, that's what you should be doing with your `cfparam`s and validation.

In the situation where you don't need to have a friendly response, such as a bot or a request that is obviously a hack or probing, there's the additional option to serve a "400" response code.  The w3c defines the response as "The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied." [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) and "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications." [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).